# approximate symbolic function to 0

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation

I have a function  which contains multiplications of symbolic constants,a[i,j], that are small, for example:

```
f = a[1, 1]*a[2, 3]*aa[1, 1]+a[1, 2]*a[2, 3]+a[1, 3]*aa[1, 5]*a[1, 4]*a[1, 3]
```

How can I eliminate the terms that contain the multiplication of 3 terms         a[i, j] or more terms, since the value of the set tends to 0?.

I try use the function DeleteCase, but I have not had a result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this has appeared before but cannot find the right link. Anyway, one approach is to make a series in a new variable after multiplying each original variable by that new one. Then set that new variable to unity.

```
removeToOrder[poly_, n_] := Module[{t, vars, tpoly},
  vars = Variables[poly];
  tpoly = poly /. Thread[vars -> t*vars];
  Normal[Series[tpoly, {t, 0, n - 1}]] /. t -> 1]
```

The example:

```
f = a[1, 1]*a[2, 3]*aa[1, 1] + a[1, 2]*a[2, 3] + 
   a[1, 3]*aa[1, 5]*a[1, 4]*a[1, 3];

removeToOrder[f, 3]

(* Out[124]= a[1, 2] a[2, 3] *)
```

Comment: I didn't know how to contact you. There used to be an interesting notebook located here http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/321/ from a presentation you did. Would it be possible to upload it again ? Or has it been deleted for any reason ? Thank you

Comment: @faysou I have no idea what happened to the library.w.c html or notebook version of "Data Structures and Efficient Algorithms in Mathematica" but I'll ask around. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @faysou It's back again, under Downloads.

Comment: Ok thank you Daniel.